# Grouping by and Combining the Strings

Tags: python, r, group-by, aggregate

To simplify my issue, I created a small DataFrame, which looks like as follows:

```
Type  From  To
A    "H1"  "U1"
A    "H9"  "I8"
A    "H1"  "IL"
B    "P2"  "P8"
B    "P2"  "P7"
C    "P9"  "O8"
C    "P9"  "I0"
C    "P7"  "O8"
```

after grouping by and concatinating the strings, we should get the following desired result:

```
Type  From  To 
A    "H1"  "U1, IL"
A    "H9"  "I8"
B    "P2"  "P8, P7"
C    "P9"  "O8, I0"
C    "P7"  "O8"
```

I did it i `R` using `split` and `aggregate` functions. For any idea or suggestion how it is possible to get in Python I would be highly thankful!

Comment: Don't tag R if you need a solution in python :)

Comment: `df.groupby(['Type','From'])['To'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ', '.join(x)).reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, we can do a group by `paste`.  (Note there was an `R` tag in the question when it was posted first.  Otherwise, we wouldn't even attempt this `R` solution)

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Type, From) %>%
    summarise(To = toString(To))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Type [?]
#  Type  From  To    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#1 A     H1    U1, IL
#2 A     H9    I8    
#3 B     P2    P8, P7
#4 C     P7    O8    
#5 C     P9    O8, I0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"
), From = c("H1", "H9", "H1", "P2", "P2", "P9", "P9", "P7"), 
To = c("U1", "I8", "IL", "P8", "P7", "O8", "I0", "O8")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -8L))
```

---

In `python`, we can do

```
out = df2.groupby(['Type', 'From'])['To'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
print(out)
# Type From     To
#0    A   H1  U1,IL
#1    A   H9     I8
#2    B   P2  P8,P7
#3    C   P7     O8
#4    C   P9  O8,I0
```

#### data

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], \
                'From': ['H1', 'H9', 'H1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P9', 'P9', 'P7'], \
                'To': ['U1', 'I8', 'IL', 'P8', 'P7', 'O8', 'I0', 'O8']})
```

Comment: That's really great! Let's think through, how we can implement it in python.

Comment: Question's about `python` not `r`.

Answer (score 5):

Using pandas -

```
df.groupby('From', as_index=False).agg({'To':', '.join, 'Type':'first'} )
```

Answer (score 2):

Call it a hack.

```
df['To']= df['To'].apply(lambda x: x +',')
df = df.groupby(['Type','From'])['To'].sum().reset_index()
df['To'] = df['To'].apply(lambda x:x.rstrip(','))
```

Comment: Add `df['To'].str.rstrip(',')` in the end to remove extra `,`

Answer (score 0):

It is also easy to implement using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from pipda import register_func
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, group_by, summarise
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.Type,  f.From,  f.To,
...     "A",     "H1",    "U1",
...     "A",     "H9",    "I8",
...     "A",     "H1",    "IL",
...     "B",     "P2",    "P8",
...     "B",     "P2",    "P7",
...     "C",     "P9",    "O8",
...     "C",     "P9",    "I0",
...     "C",     "P7",    "O8",
... )
>>> 
>>> @register_func(None)
... def paste(x, sep=', '):
...     return sep.join(x)
... 
>>> df >> group_by(f.Type, f.From) >> summarise(To=paste(f.To))
[2021-06-11 18:13:18][datar][   INFO] `summarise()` has grouped output by ['Type'] (override with `_gro
ups` argument)
      Type     From       To
  <object> <object> <object>
0        A       H1   U1, IL
1        A       H9       I8
2        B       P2   P8, P7
3        C       P7       O8
4        C       P9   O8, I0
[Groups: ['Type'] (n=3)]
>>> df >> group_by(f.Type, f.From) >> summarise(To=paste(f.To, sep=';'))
[2021-06-11 18:13:52][datar][   INFO] `summarise()` has grouped output by ['Type'] (override with `_gro
ups` argument)
      Type     From       To
  <object> <object> <object>
0        A       H1    U1;IL
1        A       H9       I8
2        B       P2    P8;P7
3        C       P7       O8
4        C       P9    O8;I0
[Groups: ['Type'] (n=3)]
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.